# debian apt update doesn't allow DVD's

Tags: debian, apt-get

i really start to pull my hair out. I have a debian 9 system **without** internet access and try to do an apt update. But i always receive the same error message (see below). I tried severall options to allow insecure repositorys, but nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help.

```
# apt update
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Contents of sources.list:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main
```

Here is my apt-config, maybe it can she some light into this:

```
# apt-config dump
APT "";
APT::Architecture "amd64";
APT::Build-Essential "";
APT::Build-Essential:: "build-essential";
APT::Install-Recommends "1";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
APT::Sandbox "";
APT::Sandbox::User "_apt";
APT::Authentication "";
APT::Authentication::TrustCDROM "true";
APT::NeverAutoRemove "";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^firmware-linux.*";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-firmware$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-image-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-image-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-headers-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-headers-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-image-extra-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-image-extra-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-signed-image-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-signed-image-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^kfreebsd-image-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^kfreebsd-image-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^kfreebsd-headers-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^kfreebsd-headers-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^gnumach-image-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^gnumach-image-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^.*-modules-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^.*-modules-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^.*-kernel-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^.*-kernel-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-backports-modules-.*-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-backports-modules-.*-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-tools-3\.16\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::NeverAutoRemove:: "^linux-tools-4\.9\.0-4-amd64$";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages "";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-image";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-headers";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-image-extra";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-signed-image";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "kfreebsd-image";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "kfreebsd-headers";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "gnumach-image";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: ".*-modules";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: ".*-kernel";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-backports-modules-.*";
APT::VersionedKernelPackages:: "linux-tools";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections "";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "metapackages";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "contrib/metapackages";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "non-free/metapackages";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "restricted/metapackages";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "universe/metapackages";
APT::Never-MarkAuto-Sections:: "multiverse/metapackages";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections "";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "oldlibs";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "contrib/oldlibs";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "non-free/oldlibs";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "restricted/oldlibs";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "universe/oldlibs";
APT::Move-Autobit-Sections:: "multiverse/oldlibs";
APT::Architectures "";
APT::Architectures:: "amd64";
APT::Architectures:: "i386";
APT::Compressor "";
APT::Compressor::. "";
APT::Compressor::.::Name ".";
APT::Compressor::.::Extension "";
APT::Compressor::.::Binary "";
APT::Compressor::.::Cost "0";
APT::Compressor::lz4 "";
APT::Compressor::lz4::Name "lz4";
APT::Compressor::lz4::Extension ".lz4";
APT::Compressor::lz4::Binary "false";
APT::Compressor::lz4::Cost "50";
APT::Compressor::gzip "";
APT::Compressor::gzip::Name "gzip";
APT::Compressor::gzip::Extension ".gz";
APT::Compressor::gzip::Binary "gzip";
APT::Compressor::gzip::Cost "100";
APT::Compressor::gzip::CompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::gzip::CompressArg:: "-6n";
APT::Compressor::gzip::UncompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::gzip::UncompressArg:: "-d";
APT::Compressor::xz "";
APT::Compressor::xz::Name "xz";
APT::Compressor::xz::Extension ".xz";
APT::Compressor::xz::Binary "xz";
APT::Compressor::xz::Cost "200";
APT::Compressor::xz::CompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::xz::CompressArg:: "-6";
APT::Compressor::xz::UncompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::xz::UncompressArg:: "-d";
APT::Compressor::bzip2 "";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::Name "bzip2";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::Extension ".bz2";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::Binary "bzip2";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::Cost "300";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::CompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::CompressArg:: "-6";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::UncompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::bzip2::UncompressArg:: "-d";
APT::Compressor::lzma "";
APT::Compressor::lzma::Name "lzma";
APT::Compressor::lzma::Extension ".lzma";
APT::Compressor::lzma::Binary "xz";
APT::Compressor::lzma::Cost "400";
APT::Compressor::lzma::CompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::lzma::CompressArg:: "--format=lzma";
APT::Compressor::lzma::CompressArg:: "-6";
APT::Compressor::lzma::UncompressArg "";
APT::Compressor::lzma::UncompressArg:: "--format=lzma";
APT::Compressor::lzma::UncompressArg:: "-d";
Dir "/";
Dir::State "var/lib/apt";
Dir::State::lists "lists/";
Dir::State::cdroms "cdroms.list";
Dir::State::mirrors "mirrors/";
Dir::State::extended_states "extended_states";
Dir::State::status "/var/lib/dpkg/status";
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
Dir::Etc "etc/apt";
Dir::Etc::sourcelist "sources.list";
Dir::Etc::sourceparts "sources.list.d";
Dir::Etc::main "apt.conf";
Dir::Etc::netrc "auth.conf";
Dir::Etc::parts "apt.conf.d";
Dir::Etc::preferences "preferences";
Dir::Etc::preferencesparts "preferences.d";
Dir::Etc::trusted "trusted.gpg";
Dir::Etc::trustedparts "trusted.gpg.d";
Dir::Bin "";
Dir::Bin::methods "/usr/lib/apt/methods";
Dir::Bin::solvers "";
Dir::Bin::solvers:: "/usr/lib/apt/solvers";
Dir::Bin::planners "";
Dir::Bin::planners:: "/usr/lib/apt/planners";
Dir::Bin::dpkg "/usr/bin/dpkg";
Dir::Bin::gzip "/bin/gzip";
Dir::Bin::bzip2 "/bin/bzip2";
Dir::Bin::xz "/usr/bin/xz";
Dir::Bin::lz4 "/usr/bin/lz4";
Dir::Bin::lzma "/usr/bin/xz";
Dir::Media "";
Dir::Media::MountPath "/media/cdrom";
Dir::Log "var/log/apt";
Dir::Log::Terminal "term.log";
Dir::Log::History "history.log";
Dir::Log::Planner "eipp.log.xz";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently "";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "~$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.disabled$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.bak$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.dpkg-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.ucf-[a-z]+$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.save$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.orig$";
Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.distUpgrade$";
Acquire "";
Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "0";
Acquire::AllowWeakRepositories "0";
Acquire::AllowDowngradeToInsecureRepositories "0";
Acquire::cdrom "";
Acquire::cdrom::mount "/media/cdrom";
Acquire::IndexTargets "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::MetaKey "$(COMPONENT)/binary-$(ARCHITECTURE)/Packages";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::flatMetaKey "Packages";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::ShortDescription "Packages";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) $(ARCHITECTURE) Packages";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::flatDescription "$(RELEASE) Packages";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Packages::Optional "0";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations::MetaKey "$(COMPONENT)/i18n/Translation-$(LANGUAGE)";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations::flatMetaKey "$(LANGUAGE)";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations::ShortDescription "Translation-$(LANGUAGE)";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations::Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) Translation-$(LANGUAGE)";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb::Translations::flatDescription "$(RELEASE) Translation-$(LANGUAGE)";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources "";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::MetaKey "$(COMPONENT)/source/Sources";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::flatMetaKey "Sources";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::ShortDescription "Sources";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) Sources";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::flatDescription "$(RELEASE) Sources";
Acquire::IndexTargets::deb-src::Sources::Optional "0";
Acquire::Changelogs "";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI "";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin "";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Debian "http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Tanglu "http://metadata.tanglu.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Ubuntu "http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/@CHANGEPATH@/changelog";
Acquire::Changelogs::URI::Origin::Ultimedia "http://packages.ultimediaos.com/changelogs/pool/@CHANGEPATH@/changelog.txt";
Acquire::Changelogs::AlwaysOnline "";
Acquire::Changelogs::AlwaysOnline::Origin "";
Acquire::Changelogs::AlwaysOnline::Origin::Ubuntu "1";
Acquire::Languages "";
Acquire::Languages:: "en_US";
Acquire::Languages:: "en";
Acquire::Languages:: "none";
Acquire::CompressionTypes "";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::xz "xz";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::bz2 "bzip2";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::lzma "lzma";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::gz "gzip";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::lz4 "lz4";
DPkg "";
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs "";
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs:: "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10";
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs:: "/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";
DPkg::Tools "";
DPkg::Tools::Options "";
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges "";
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::Version "2";
DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::InfoFD "20";
Dpkg:Progress-Fancy "1";
Binary "apt-config";
Binary::apt "";
Binary::apt::APT "";
Binary::apt::APT::Color "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Show "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Show::Version "2";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::AllVersions "0";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowVirtuals "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Search "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Search::Version "2";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowDependencyType "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowVersion "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Get "";
Binary::apt::APT::Get::Upgrade-Allow-New "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cmd "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cmd::Show-Update-Stats "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "0";
Binary::apt::DPkg "";
Binary::apt::DPkg::Progress-Fancy "1";
Binary::apt-get "";
Binary::apt-get::Acquire "";
Binary::apt-get::Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "1";
CommandLine "";
CommandLine::AsString "apt-config dump";
```

**apt** --allow-unauthenticated update

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**apt-get** --allow-unauthenticated update

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Err:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/dists/stretch/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

## Update 1

With the `sources.list`changed the output at the end of `apt update` is different now:

sources.list

```
deb [ trusted=yes ] cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main
```

apt update

```
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch Release
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib i386 Packages
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main all Packages
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/main Translation-en_US
Err:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25] stretch/contrib all Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/dists/stretch/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

## Update 2

I just realised i had setup a multiarch with i386. i now removed it with `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`. There were no i386 packages installed.
I then removed the DVD from `sources.list` and re-added it with `apt-cdrom.`
Result stays the same.

Comment: Have you tried removing the cdrom from sources.list and then adding it using apt-cdrom? See documentation: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-cdrom.8.en.html

Comment: yes, i tried. even downloaded the iso again. apt-cdrom add works, apt update fails.

Comment: What about `--allow-unauthenticated` option of `apt-get` (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) or `Trusted` option of `sources.list` (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html)?

Comment: Please see my question for the outputs of `--allow-unauthenticated`. If i understand `trusted` cotrrectly i just append it to the deb line, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in the question and comments, the only thing you are using wrong is `trusted` option.

Your `sources.list` uses one-line-style format (see [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/sources.list.5.en.html)), so the correct entry to make your cdrom trusted would be:

```
deb [ trusted=yes ] cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main
```

Edit: There are some other options related to repository security, you can try:

```
deb [ trusted=yes allow-insecure=yes allow-weak=yes allow-downgrade-to-insecure=yes ] cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.5.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180714-10:25]/ stretch contrib main
```

Comment: With this the output is different and ends in (with the dvd mounted). Please see question in a few minutes.

Comment: See my edit for more options to try.

Comment: Output looks the same as with only `trusted=yes`. "Failed to fetch cdrom. Some index files failed to download"

Comment: After removing multiarch **and** adding the `trusted` to the options i get some upgradeable packages. But still a lot of `Ignored`

Comment: Is it possible that the DVD contains only packages for architecture amd64?

Comment: Yes. So i wonder now, i feel like we passed into another question now. And in a sense your answer is correct. I still need the `trusted`. So i guess i'll mark it as solved and open a new question?

Comment: That seems to better option than discussing this further in the comments.